# What does -fnoninteractive mean in a call to debconf-communicate?

Tags: debconf

My title is the question.
I'm looking at a script which makes a popen call to debconf-communicate with a cli argument -fnoninteractive.

What does the -fnoninteractive do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-f` option specifies a frontend.  This is documented in the `debconf-communicate --help` message:

```
  -f,  --frontend               Specify debconf frontend to use.
```

So, `-fnoninteractive` specifies the "noninteractive" frontend.  The behavior of this frontend is explained in `man 7 debconf` (or the online version [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/debconf.7.html)) which reads:

```
   noninteractive
          This is the anti-frontend. It never interacts with you  at  all,
          and  makes  the  default  answers  be used for all questions. It
          might mail error messages to root, but that’s it;  otherwise  it
          is  completely  silent  and  unobtrusive, a perfect frontend for
          automatic installs.   If  you  are  using  this  front-end,  and
          require  non-default  answers  to  questions,  you  will need to
          preseed  the  debconf  database;  see  the  section   below   on
          Unattended Package Installation for more details.
```

In other words, `-fnoninteractive` means what is says: the program doesn't try to interact with you, making it suitable for automated scripts.

If you want still more detail, the perl source code for "noninteractive" and the other frontends is in `/usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Element`.